# Windows Service - Retrieving wrong AppConfig key

Tags: vb.net, service, path, app-config

I'm developing an application as a windows service. The service retrieves a path from `app.config`, but   for some reason part of the retrieved path is changing during the execution and replaced with `C:\Windows\System32`.

This is my app.config

```
[...]
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Freq_Minutes" value="1" />
    <add key="Connectionstring" value="Server=FENIX\SQL2005;Database=amoselprat;Uid=amos;Pwd=mosa;"/>
    <add key="AMOSEsdara_Path" value="C:\TEMP\AMOS_ESDARA"/>
    <add key="EsdaraAMOS_Path" value="C:\TEMP\ESDARA_AMOS"/>
  </appSettings >
[...]
```

This is the function that retrieves the key

```
Public Function GetInfo(ByVal Label As String) As String
    Dim Value As String

    Try
        Value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(Label).ToString

    Catch ex As Exception
        Value = Nothing
    End Try
    Return Value

End Function
```

And this is troubled code

```
    Public Sub Components(ByVal AutoNumber As String)

        Dim sw As StreamWriter
        Dim File As String

        File = GetInfo("AMOSEsdara_Path") & "\AMOS_ESDA_COMP_" & Autonumber & ".xml"

        Try

            EventLog_AMOSEsdara.WriteEntry("AMOSEsdara Interface - Creating components file " & File)
            sw = File.CreateText(File)

[...]

    Catch Ex As Exception

        EventLog_AMOSEsdara.WriteEntry("AMOSEsdara Interface - Error creating file " & File & " Error: " & Ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Running as a service EventLog is writting the below error:

```
AMOSEsdara Interface - Error creating file AMOS_ESDARA\AMOS_ESDA_COMP_000006.xml Error: Can not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\AMOS_ESDARA\AMOS_ESDA_COMP_000006.xml'.
```

I tried to use the same code into a Console Application instead Service Application and it is working fine. The retrieved path is correct and the XML file is created successfully at `C:\TEMP\AMOS_ESDARA`

What I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer to your issue, but calling `ToString()` on `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` is redudnant, as that returns a string (or null if the key is not found).  You can remove that and the associated `try-catch` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
    Public Function GetInfo(ByVal Label As String) As String
        Dim Value As String


    System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory((System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory))

        Try
            Value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(Label).ToString

        Catch ex As Exception
            Value = Nothing
        End Try
        Return Value

End Function
```